# Getting Image from camera registers

Tags: c#, image, camera

I'm working on a simple imaging software for my University, and I ran into annoying problem while getting image from camera.
There is an .dll COM library for camera Apogee Alta U57 (Library and documentation is here: http://www.ccd.com/downloads.html) and there are two possible ways of getting image from camera (provided that image is ready):

1. using  "ICamera2 camera.image", which returns

   > "Returns a 2D SAFEARRAY, of type LONG (4 bytes per
   >   element) or INTEGER (2 bytes per element), which contains
   >   the image data. The type of data (LONG or INTEGER)
   >   returned is controlled by the associated property of
   >   ConvertShortToLong."
2. using "ICamera2.GetImage(int pImageBuffer)" which is described as:

   > Returns a pointer to 16 bit, unsigned short data located
   >   in memory. The image data region should be allocated by the
   >   application prior to calling this method.

And I'm pretty well confused while using second method, because int != int* ,
and I really don't know how to pass POINTER TO 16 BIT USHORT.
My simplified method of getting image looks like this:

```
        public unsafe uint[] getImage(int width, int height)
    {
        // Allocating array of image size (width * height)
        // where pixel is size of unsigned int (4 BYTES)
        // possible values: 0 to 4,294,967,295 
        uint[] pixels = new uint[width * height];

        // Gets pointer to allocated array and fixes it, 
        // so that it won't be moved by Garbage Collector
        fixed (uint* ptr = pixels)
        {
            camera.GetImage(ptr);
        }
        return pixels;
    }
```

Anyone can explain? I'm really tired (been coding for past 10 hours) and maybe I'm missing something :(

Comment: What is your problem? Are you able to get an image or not? You should also post the actual signatures of those functions, not just the documentation.

Comment: @xxbbcc Problem is that my compiler rejects "camera.GetImage(ptr)"
As for signatures of functions there is only .dll library, which contains interfaces: 
      [DispId(6)]
       void GetImage(int pImageBuffer);
       [DispId(7)]

Comment: What happens if you open the DLL with the Type Library Viewer? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx

Comment: @xxbbcc correct me if I'm wrong, but I viewed it with Type Lib Viewer, and with path: APOGEELib -> coclass Camera2 ->ICamera2-> Methods-> GetImagei got: [id(0x00000006), helpstring("method GetImage")] HRESULT GetImage([in] long pImageBuffer);

Comment: Ok - I added an answer to cast your pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like your `GetImage` function expects you to allocate the memory for image pixels and pass in a pointer to that allocated memory. You're also responsible for freeing up that memory when you're done with it.

I think the only change you need to do is casting your pointer to a `long` - the `GetImage` function takes a `long`, not a pointer (on 32-bit platforms, the pointer would be 32 bits; on 64-bit platforms, it'd be 64 bits).

```
// Gets pointer to allocated array and fixes it, 
// so that it won't be moved by Garbage Collector
fixed (uint* ptr = pixels)
{
    long ptrValue = (long) ptr;

    camera.GetImage(ptrValue);
}
```

This cast is not terribly nice but it's safe since the number of bits is adequate for both platforms. (I suspect you already have to target either 32-bit or 64-bit platforms anyway.)

Comment: Yay, it works! Anyway, GetImage takes int value of ptr, so I changed long to int. Compiler is ok with that. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Badylu I'm glad it works but what do you mean 'int value of ptr'? What platform are you targeting? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: I'm targetting 32-bit platform, and my VS2013 is sure that GetImage takes "int" value, not long (even though it's "long" in documentation) :(

Comment: @Badylu Ok, as long as you're targeting 32-bit platforms, you're fine.

Comment: as "long" as you're... <- I see what you did there :) Thank you once more! Have a nice day/night or whatever else is outside :)

Answer (score -1):

The documentation say it want an Uint16.  I though you should be doing something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Apogee.dll.dll")]
        extern static int CreateInstance(out IntPtr ICamera2Ptr);

        [DllImport("Apogee.dll.dll")]
        extern static void GetImage(ref IntPtr pImageBuffer);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr ICamera2Ptr;
            int results = CreateInstance(out ICamera2Ptr);

        }
        static UInt16[] getImage(int width, int height)
        {
            // Allocating array of image size (width * height)
            // where pixel is size of unsigned int (4 BYTES)
            // possible values: 0 to 4,294,967,295 

            // Allocate memory and calculate a byte count 
            //unsigned short *pBuffer = new unsigned short[ ImgXSize * ImgYSize ];
            //unsigned long ImgSizeBytes = ImgXSize * ImgYSize * 2; 

            UInt16[] pixels = new UInt16[width * height];
            IntPtr unmanaged_pPixels = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(pixels));

            //// External operations ApogeeCamera->ExternalShutter = true; 
            //ApogeeCamera->ExternalIoReadout = false; 
            //ApogeeCamera->IoPortAssignment = 0x08; 
            // Even though the exposure time will not be used, still call Expose 
            //ApogeeCamera->Expose( 0.001, true ); 
            // Check camera status to make sure image data is ready 
            //while (ApogeeCamera->ImagingStatus != Apn_Status_ImageReady ); 
            // Get the image data from the camera ApogeeCamera->GetImage( (long)pBuffer );


            GetImage(ref unmanaged_pPixels);
            pixels = (UInt16[])Marshal.PtrToStructure(unmanaged_pPixels, typeof(UInt16[]));
            return pixels;


        }
    }
}
​
```